# How to select User certificates from edge browser using Playwright with Java

Tags: java, automation, playwright

How to select User certificates from edge browser using Playwright with Java.

We have different certificate added in browser for each role and we need to select using Playwright. We are using Jave as language binding

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You mean probably supporting client certificates, this is not supported yet: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/1799